# JMS Serializer can not set context target attribute on Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, jms, serialization

I am using Symfony Flex 4.1.2 i trying update object entity with JMS serializer.

```
   $userService = $this->get('user.service');
   $user = $userService->findByOne(array('id' => 1));

   $data = [
      "spotifyAccessToken" => $accessToken
   ];

   $context = new DeserializationContext();
   $context = $context->setAttribute('target', $user);
   $content = json_encode($data);
   $serializedData = $serializer->deserialize($content, User::class, 'json', $context);
```

**$user** is object of **User::class** i dumped in order of $user, $context and $serialized data, output is below

```
User {#498 ▼
+id: 2
+userName: "spotify:user:1199928833"
+spotifyUserId: "1199928833"
+spotifyAccessToken: "TEST"
+spotifyRefreshToken: "TEST"
+email: "TEST"
+birthday: DateTime @857174400 {#496 ▶}
+image: "TEST"
}
DeserializationContext {#502 ▼
-depth: 0
+attributes: Map {#508 ▼
#elements: array:1 [▼
  "target" => User {#498 ▼
    +id: 2
    +userName: "spotify:user:1199928833"
    +spotifyUserId: "1199928833"
    +spotifyAccessToken: "TEST"
    +spotifyRefreshToken: "TEST"
    +email: "TEST"
    +birthday: DateTime @857174400 {#496 ▶}
    +image: "TEST"
  }
]
}
-format: null
-visitor: null
-navigator: null
-metadataFactory: null
-exclusionStrategy: null
-serializeNull: null
-initialized: false
-metadataStack: null
}
User {#536 ▼
+id: null
+userName: null
+spotifyUserId: null
+spotifyAccessToken: "UPDATED_ACCESS_TOKEN"
+spotifyRefreshToken: null
+email: null
+birthday: null
+image: null
}
```

So JMS did not deserialize with user object, how can i fix it?

Answer (score -1):

It seems fine to me, you're creating an `User` object from

```
$data = [
    "spotifyAccessToken" => $accessToken
];
```

hence you're receiving

```
+id: null
+userName: null
+spotifyUserId: null
+spotifyAccessToken: "UPDATED_ACCESS_TOKEN"
+spotifyRefreshToken: null
+email: null
+birthday: null
+image: null
```

so why are you expecting a complete `User` object?

Now if you need a full `User` object with updated `spotifyAccessToken` I would do something like:

```
$user->setSpotifyAccessToken($accessToken); // supposing you have a setter for it
$serializedUser = json_encode($user);
$unserializedUser = $serializer->deserialize($serializedUser, User::class, 'json');
```

Comment: We should use serializer, if i use it, we dont need a serializer, i trying update an object